# Dynamically setting date and time in DateBox Jquery Mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, datepicker, datebox

I need to populate date and time dynamically to JQuery DataBox input field. I teried to do but it is populating the current date in the input fields irrespective of the data I pass.

Here is the date picker which I am cloning to dynamically have in my interface.

Html:-

```
<input class="time-input day-time-picker day-time-picker-inline-input"  type="text" data-role="datebox" data-options='{"mode":"datebox", "useFocus": true}' style="width:8em" />
```

Javascript:-

```
var datePicker = $("#date-time-picker-template-container .date-time-picker-template").clone();
```

Similar way I created a time picker and cloned as did above,

Html :-

```
var timePicker = $("#time-picker-template-container .time-picker-template").clone();
```

Javascript :-

```
<input class="time-input day-time-picker day-time-picker-inline-input" type="text" data-role="datebox" data-options='{"mode":"timebox", "useFocus": true}' />
```

Inserting Date

```
$(".time-input",  datePicker).datebox();

$(".time-input",  datePicker).datebox("refresh");

$(".time-input",  datePicker).datebox('setTheDate', dynamicDate);
```

Inserting Time

```
$(".time-input",  dayTimePicker).datebox();

 $(".time-input",  dayTimePicker).datebox("refresh");

 $(".time-input",  dayTimePicker).val('datebox', {'method':'set', 'value':dynamicTime});
```

I want to set date and time to these DateBox input fields dynamically based on the response I get.

Is there any control to get date and time in a single control using DateBox ?

Thanks.

Comment: Where did you set value of DateBox in the code? Clone will ignore the value field.

Comment: Edited the question. Now it has code to insert date and time. Clone will not hold the value ?

Comment: No it will not hold. So you have to set the value after cloning it.

Comment: But I am aslo setting the value after cloning only. But still it is showing current date and not the set date.

Comment: Can I know any possible way to get it right so that I can try and move forward

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clone your templates, add them to a container DOM element and then tell the element to enhanceWithin(). This creates the databox widgets, then set the date and time using the setTheDate method:

```
$("#btnAdd").on("click", function(){
    var dynamicDate = new Date(2014,3,22,10,11,0,0);

    var datePicker = $("#templates .date-time-picker-template").clone();
    var dayTimePicker = $("#templates .time-picker-template").clone();
    $("#time-picker-block").append(datePicker).append(dayTimePicker).enhanceWithin(); 

    $(".date-input",  datePicker).datebox('setTheDate', dynamicDate);
    $(".time-input",  dayTimePicker).datebox('setTheDate', dynamicDate);
});
```

> **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/ggd7vzqc/4/)**

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I follow what it is you are trying to accomplish, but yes, there is a mode that allows both date and time operation at the same time - slidebox.

You will need to set (at least) the following options:

```
{
  mode = "slidebox",
  overrideSlideFieldOrder = ["y","m","d","h","i"],
  overrideDateFormat = "%Y-%m-%d %k:%M
}
```

For what it's worth, flipbox could *probably* be altered to work with both, but it's non-trivial.  datebox can likely already work (I've never tried), but you'll need to pretty heavily alter the CSS - at least making the control a good deal wider first.